# Create 2 log file in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

I creating multiple log file in `Springboot` , `log-back.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="HOME" value="./logs" />
    <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">-->
        <syslogHost>10.0.3.20</syslogHost>
        <facility>SYSLOG</facility>
        <suffixPattern>abc [%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME}/abc.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/abc.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

‌

```
// another log file 
    <appender name="FILE"   class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME}mon.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/mon.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.rh.project" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="mail-log" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

When I check inside log directory, I only saw `abc.log` , but no `mon.log`

Comment: this is an incomplete logback.xml; and you do not show how you log to the loggers.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @P.J.Meisch post edited. It is the complete `logback.xml` now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice the slash missing inside  in second logger??

```
<file>${HOME}/mon.log</file>
```

I believe that's the problem. However, nothing to do with spring boot :)